# SQL Server 2000 clustering

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2000 2000 box that has a Active/Passive Cluster. My network guys are changing the IP address for private IP on both nodes db01 db02 to 192.168.0.1 and 0.2 and also, removing the BACKUP network resource from cluster admin. I have to do the failover after they change the configuration on Cluster Admin. Can anyone please tell me the steps to do the failover? I would really appreciate this, Since this is my first time doing the failover.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917693.aspx) provides some really good information.
hih